# Manipulação de Data

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Gostaria de saber se é possível, depois de converter a data e trazer apenas a hora, manipular esse esse resultado para retornar a hora fechada. O exemplo abaixo detalha melhor.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), DATEADD(second, cr.open_date ,'1969-12-31 21:00:00'), 121) as 'Data de Abertura',
CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), datepart(hh, DATEADD(second, cr.open_date ,'1969-12-31 21:00:00'))) as 'Hora Abertura',
```

O código acima retorna esse resultado:

2018-01-23 08:53:35 ------ 8

2018-01-23 15:59:44 ------ 15

Neste caso, gostaria de pegar o valor e transformar em data fechada assim: o 8 em 8:00:00, o 15 em 15:00:00. Não encontrei uma maneira. Estou pegando os dados, passando para uma planilha do Excel e criando uma macro para realizar esse procedimento.

Também tentei algo desse tipo:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(hour, DATEADD(SECOND, cr.open_date,'1969-12-31 21:00:00'), ''), 114) as 'Data fechada'
```

No entanto apresenta um erro: "Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function."

Gostaria de saber se há algum modo de realizar.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função `DATEADD` da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(HOUR, 8, ''), 114);
```

O exemplo acima resultará em `08:00:00`.

Aplicando na sua `query`:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HH, DATEADD(SECOND, cr.open_date ,'1969-12-31 21:00:00')), 114) AS 'Hora Abertura'
```

Comment: @Pesati adicionei a informação que você precisa no final da minha resposta. Verifique se atende ao que você deseja.

Comment: Olá @Sorack, fiz o teste, mas ele retorna dessa maneira:

Apr 25 1900  8:00AM